# How to fix blank Minicart popup in custom navbar for Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, frontend, requirejs, mini-cart

I am creating a custom theme from the parent theme Luma. I've added this code to Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml to include the minicart.

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" name="minicart" as="minicart" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/minicart.phtml"/>
```

The result added the cart icon but when clicked on, it only shows a blank popup. This stays blank whether there is a product added to cart or not. There is no error messages in console.

[image]

[image: Minicart Page Source on my site]

[image: Working Website Page Source]

Comment: I switched my theme back to Luma and the cart does work, so it must be something in my custom theme that is breaking it, but I'm not sure what to look for

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing child theme based on parent theme Luma you can just move minicart block

```
<move element="minicart" destination="your.container" />
```

Comment: If I do this then the cart doesn't even show

Comment: For example if I set the destination to "header-wrapper", then clear the cache and then it shows nothing on the frontend.